# How to manually resend email verification in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, verification

I have an admin page on my site and I want an option to be able to manually resend an email verification, there are two purposes for this:

1. Test email verifications templates.
2. Debug user issues.

Does the user model have a method to do this?

Comment: 1>Do you mean manually sending per email address? 2> You want to verify user via email (similar to activation)?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If your `User` model implements the `MustVerifyEmail` interface, yes, you can manually send the notification using:

```
$user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
```

Comment: Call to a member function sendEmailVerificationNotification() on null

Comment: @SeadLab yup, that means that you don't have a `user` on which you are calling the method on. So `$user` should be first found, either through the `Auth` or querying the database.

Comment: No, the problem is, I use this tutorial to add verification email feature https://www.5balloons.info/user-email-verification-and-account-activation-in-laravel-5-5/

Then, I realized, i am not be able to resend verification email. So I leave the tutorial above, and I just implements MustVerifyEmail, it work's like a charm. 

Now, I have another problem, I want to add feature for user who want to cancel the proccess of verification email.

Comment: @SeadLab for that you can start a new thread by asking what exactly is your problem and what you have tried, so someone in the community can help you.

Comment: And what if your user model does not implement MustVerifyEmail?

Comment: It still works! Wow! After many hours... It works even without implementing MustVerifyEmail

Comment: Never exptected what I need just a single line of code